$A^{p^{n!}}-A$ is nilpotent in $M_n(\mathbb{F}_p)$
As mentioned in the title I want to show $A^{p^{n!}}-A$ is nilpotent matrix for any $n\times n$ matrix $A$ with elements in $\mathbb{F}_{p}$. So far I only know if $\lambda$ is eigenvalue of $A$, then $\lambda\in \mathbb{F}_{p^{n!}}$ since the minimal polynomial of $A$ has at most degree $n$, so its splitting field is subfield of $\mathbb{F}_{p^{n!}}$. Since $\lambda^{p^{n!}}$ eigenvalue of $A^{p^{n!}}$ and $\lambda^{p^{n!}}=\lambda$, then $\lambda$ is also eigenvalue of $A^{p^{n!}}$. Therefore, $A$ and $A^{p^{n!}}$ have the same set of eigenvalues. Now I am not sure how to go from this.

Try considering the Jordan canonical form of $A$ over $\overline{\mathbb{F}_p}$.

@DanielSchepler I am having difficulty with Jordan form of $A^{p^{n!}}$. How do I know this?

Well, if $J_{\lambda,k}$ is the standard Jordan block of size $k$ for eigenvalue $\lambda$, then $J_{\lambda,k}^m$ is an upper triangular matrix with all diagonal entries equal to $\lambda^m$.  (In fact, IIRC, the "next diagonal up" has entries $m \lambda^{m-1}$, then the next up has entries $\binom{m}{2} \lambda^{m-2}$, and so on.  But that detail doesn't look like it will end up being that important.)

@DanielSchepler I see, thank you, I got it. So the difference has strict upper triangular form right?

Right. (And filler to satisfy minimum comment length.)

Laurence, if you figured it out, you can post a summary as an answer. Just to get more feedback (checks/comments/upvotes). That is, unless @DanielSchepler wants to do it :-) The point is that your question won't get stuck here unanswered (when somebody else, years from now, may start thinking about it etc...)

@JyrkiLahtonen OK, let me wait a bit, if no one answer I will put it.

This answer is based on Daniel Schepler's comments. Let $A=PJP^{-1}$ where $J$ is the Jordan Normal form of $A$ over $\mathbb{F}_{p^{n!}}$. Note that actually entries of $P$ are also in $\mathbb{F}_{p^{n!}}$. Then by factoring out $P$ and $P^{-1}$, we may assume $A=J$. Now if $J_1,\dots,J_k$ are Jordan's blocks of $A$, by observation in problem, the diagonals of $J_i^{p^{n!}}$ and $J_i$ are the same for each $i$. Hence, we get that $A^{p^{n!}}-A$ is strictly upper triangular matrix, so it is nilpotent.
